# Is there a way to do collaborative equation editing in a Google Presentation?

Tags: formulas, google-slides

Since Google Docs now forbids equation in presentations (you cannot drag equation from doc anymore according to this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/adding-equations-to-google-docs-presentation)).

Is there a way to include equations in a Google Presentation?