# How to insert Mathematical Equations in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been searching for a while now and all searches lead to Google Docs, not Google Sheets. So basically what I'm looking for is similar to the insert equation function as in Excel where you can insert Mathematical Equations and symbols etc... I have an excel file that I opened using the Google Sheets but when I did, the cells where the equations were placed are left blank. All the other things are as it was like the original except the mathematical equations. I'm thinking of just turning them to images then add them as an image but I'm, wondering if there's a way I would be able to include them like in Excel.

This is what I meant by insert mathematical equation.
[image]

This should be what is displayed in a cell
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are a teacher you got lucky... and saved £80 (105.85$). There is an addon for Google Sheets called **[EquatIO](https://www.texthelp.com/en-gb/products/equatio/#)** which allows you to insert math equations. All you have to do is:

- create account at **[https://my.texthelp.com/](https://my.texthelp.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F)**
- submit this form: **https://www.texthelp.com/en-us/products/free-for-teachers/**

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Besides writing a mathematical equation using a non-Google app and inserting / pasting it as an image you could do the following:

- To write a simple mathematical equation you could type it directly in a cell

  - You might need to use your operative system font explorer to find the mathematical symbols that you need, or copy paste them from a place showing then as Unicode characters
- To write complex mathematical equations you could insert a drawing.

  - One of the advantages of inserting a drawing is that it include a Insert > Special characters menu which includes an area to draw the symbol that you to add

  [image]
- Search for a Google Sheets add-on on the Google Workspace Marketplace (click  Add-ons > Get add-ons

Related

- [Adding equations to Google Slides](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4824/88163)